# How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone without "MFMessageComposeViewController "?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sms

I would like to send an `SMS` from an iPhone but `MFMessageComposeViewController` pops up the message,I would like to send the `SMS` when an event or notification occurs in the application.Is it possible through `iOS SDK` or are there any legitimate low level function which can be used to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to send SMS messages programmatically through the iOS SDK. As you can imagine, if the SDK allowed this, it would open a huge can of worms in terms of developer abuse.

If the SMS messages don't have to come from the user's phone number, you can take a look at the Twilio API (http://www.twilio.com/sms).