# Is there any way to send a text message programmatically without having to open the default sms app in iphone?

Tags: ios, swift, sms

I have been looking for solutions to this but seem to only have been lead to a common solution where I use this chunk of code attached to a button

```
@IBAction func btnSend(sender: AnyObject) {


    var messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    messageVC.body = "Enter a message";
    messageVC.recipients = ["enter number here"]
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)}
```

and this method

```
func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
    switch (result.value) {
    case MessageComposeResultCancelled.value:
        println("Message was cancelled")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResultFailed.value:
        println("Message failed")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResultSent.value:
        println("Message was sent")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

but I do not want to be redirected to the default sms app, I want to send the text from the app that I made instead.

Is this even possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949082/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone-without-mfmessagecomposeviewcont?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is by sending the SMS not directly from the user's phone but from a distant SMS server. Notice that it also means that you will be the one paying for the text messages being sent, and not the users.